# Can't test my api on local server, always redirect to google api. After migrate to endpoints 2.0

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

All had good on endpoints 1.0. I've done all steps at [migrating](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/endpoints/migrating) 2.0 google docs. Update my project successfully, and can run endpoints api explorer. But when I try run endpoints api explorer locally (localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer) it's redirect me to google api explorer. This my app.yaml

```
application: graphofgroups
version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index\.html
  secure: always
- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js
- url: /partials
  static_dir: static/partials
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
- url: /_ah/api/.*
  script: main.app
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest

- name: pycrypto
  version: latest

- name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
inbound_services:
- mail

builtins:
- remote_api: on

env_variables:
  ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME: echo-api.endpoints.graphofgroups.appspot.com
  ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION: [2017-04-06r0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to the Google APIs Explorer is the correct behavior, but given that you are using HTTP for localhost, it prevents you from seeing your API.

There are two fixes that I've found:

1. See [this link](https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/#hitting_local_api) for details on how to restart your browser to allow this content.
2. If you're using Chrome, click on the shield in the address bar and choose "Load Unsafe Scripts". (see below)

[image]